# getSignaturesForAddress returning empty array

Tags: rpc, getsignaturesforaddress

here is an account: https://solscan.io/account/DCbsLeX1e6xahZcjuVJfni9418qAzqiwB9kQjMMk9vEg
as you can see, there are plenty of transactions to find.

when i run this code, no transactions are returned:

```
const getTransactions = async (address, numTx) => {
  const pubKey = new PublicKey(address);
  let transactionList = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(pubKey, {
    limit: numTx,
  });
  return transactionList;
};

const transactions = await getTransactions(
  "DCbsLeX1e6xahZcjuVJfni9418qAzqiwB9kQjMMk9vEg",
  10
);

console.log(transactions)
```

any and all help would be appreciated.  The goal is to be able to fetch all transactions by account.  I thought thats what getSignaturesForAddress does but it isnt working for me.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Be sure that your `connection` is on mainnet-beta!